# Workflow Add Button with Conditions

Tags: netsuite

I have created a workflow for Sales Orders with 2 states.

State 1: Create Button (before record load)

State 2: Custom Workflow Action

The workflow is set with conditions that the the Sales Orders status is not "Pending Fulfillment". However, there seems to be no rhyme or reason to when the button appears or does not appear. If I change the conditions for the workflow to include pending fulfillment (to add the button) and then revert back, the button is still there.

The workflow doesn't appear to be executing on every load of the Sales Order.

I know this is most likely not enough information, but I can answer questions that people have.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the workflow setting? It is this setting that controls if the record will enter the workflow or not.

Comment: My Understanding  in Sales Order After Status changing you need to show button?

Comment: Well, it is more on view, create or update. Whatever the status is at that point should influence whether or not the button is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I built my conditions using the "Visual Binder". When I clicked the radio button for "Formula" it showed me what the visual binder was looking at. It was looking at `transaction.statusRef.id` instead of `transaction.statusRef`. When I changed this, the workflow began behaving as I expected.